# Error while running gulp, Missing binding, node-sass couldn't find a binding

Tags: npm, binding, gulp, node-sass, gulp-sass

When I run the **gulp** command, I get this error:

```
throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
      ^

Error: Missing binding C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Project\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 6.x
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 14.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Project\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Project\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Project\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:187:21)
```

I have tried **npm rebuild node-sass** and uninstalling and reinstalling node-sass and all node_modules many times.

I am in the node version: 6.10.2, npm:6.14.14, gulp CLI version 1.2.2, Local version 3.9.1. Windows 10, x64. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall node-sass
```

then

```
npm install node-sass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Node and Gulp versions are not compatible. Either you need to update GULP or you need to downgrade Node version